# Alternative of openintents for simulating sensors for Android

Tags: java, android, simulation, open-intents

I am working on an extensible sensing and data processing framework for Android mobile devices. It will enable a wide range of data signals (e.g., Temperature, Battery,pressure, wifi signal strength, etc.) accessible via Android mobile devices.

To test sensors, I deploy my written  android code on my Android device. 
Here, the limitation comes ---my android device has a limited set of sensors 
( for example, it does not has temperature sensor) So, I can not test all  the written code for all types of sensors (e.g., temperature, pressure, etc.).

On Internet, I have checked **SensorSimulator** project (), but it does not work for me. I am getting the following errors.

```
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworldsensorsimulator/com.example.helloworldsensorsimulator.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorSimulatorClient.connect(SensorSimulatorClient.java:116)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorManagerSimulator.connectSimulator(SensorManagerSimulator.java:220)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at com.example.helloworldsensorsimulator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
05-03 01:40:40.766: E/AndroidRuntime(10139):    ... 11 more
```

I have written the following code, Suggested on the website to connect SensorSimulator through Java Project. AndroidManifest file contains the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.Sensor;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEvent;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorManagerSimulator;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SensorManagerSimulator mSensorManager;

    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerAccelerometer;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerGravity;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerLinearAcceleration;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerLight;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerTemperature;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerOrientation;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerMagneticField;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerPressure;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerRotationVector;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerBarcode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = SensorManagerSimulator.getSystemService(this,
                SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mSensorManager.connectSimulator();


        initListeners();
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        mEventListenerAccelerometer = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Accelerometer: " + values[0]
                        + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
                /*mTextViewAccelerometer.setText("Accelerometer: " + values[0]
                        + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerLinearAcceleration = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Linear Acceleration: "
                        + values[0] + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
                /*mTextViewLinearAcceleration.setText("Linear Acceleration: "
                        + values[0] + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerGravity = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Gravity: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
                /*mTextViewGravity.setText("Gravity: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerMagneticField = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;

                System.out.println("Compass: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
                /*mTextViewMagneticField.setText("Compass: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
*/          }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerOrientation = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Orientation: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
                /*mTextViewOrientation.setText("Orientation: " + values[0] + ", "
                        + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerTemperature = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Temperature: " + values[0]);
                //mTextViewTemperature.setText("Temperature: " + values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerLight = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Light: " + values[0]);
                //mTextViewLight.setText("Light: " + values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerPressure = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("Pressure: " + values[0]);
                //mTextViewPressure.setText("Pressure: " + values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
        mEventListenerRotationVector = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                System.out.println("RotationVector: " + values[0]
                        + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);
            /*  mTextViewRotationVector.setText("RotationVector: " + values[0]
                        + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]);*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };

        mEventListenerBarcode = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Barcode: " + event.barcode);
                //mTextViewBarcode.setText("Barcode: " + event.barcode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    /*  mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerAccelerometer,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerLinearAcceleration,
                mSensorManager
                        .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerGravity,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerMagneticField,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerOrientation,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);*/
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerTemperature,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        /*mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerLight,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerPressure,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerBarcode,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_BARCODE_READER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerRotationVector,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        /*mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerAccelerometer);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerLinearAcceleration);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerGravity);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerMagneticField);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerOrientation);*/
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerTemperature);
        /*mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerLight);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerPressure);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerRotationVector);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerBarcode);*/
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which device(s) are you testing with? Which ROM(s)?

Comment: It is Samsung GT-S7392. Android version 4.1.2

Comment: errrr the issue has nothing to do with openintents, you just cannot block the UI thread with network requests (ever).  `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException `  Try wrapping that in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `SensorManager.connectSimulator()` constitutes a network operation as shown by your stack trace.  Thus, you're attempting to perform network operations on your application's main thread.  Android does not allow this by default and so you have two options.

1. Use another thread or [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  The AsyncTask syntax and usage convention can be a bit confusing, so here's an example: [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).
2. [Turn off strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html#penaltyDeathOnNetwork()) *(not recommended)*.

Comment: Can you provide a sample please?

Comment: @PankeshPatel updated with a link to the AsyncTask documentation.  You simply need to put the `mSensorManager.connectSimulator();` line into the `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: Still the problem persist. I am not able to get the data from the SensorSimulator.

Comment: @PankeshPatel please update your question with new information then.  Can't read your mind.